# Dyntopo is decreasing and destroying the vertices

Tags: mesh, sculpting, remesh

I've got an issue with Dyntopo after I'm trying to Detail Flood Fill my object is getting destroyed and verticals is tremendously decreasing, after I tried to apply same on other objects the result is the same. can somebody help me to figure that out, please. [image] [image]

[image]

Comment: Make sure that the Dyntopo Derail Size is low enough? Are you trying to reduce the topology with Dyntopo?

Comment: @moonboots Added one more pict, that shows the size. As I followed the course, and thought that is some issue that isn't related to Dyntop. But if I go with size 60 then its fine.